# react design ( style ) change after making react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react design working good before buliding, after building style of whole app cannot work.

```
npm run build
```

i'm using laravel 9 in react app, i also try with Asset Bundling (Vite) but my style file ( index.css ) cannot working.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have import .css files in App.js.
Put .css files in `src/css` folder